# Java 8 partition list into groups by condition involving previous elements

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8

Suppose I have a list of intervals (sorted by start) and I want to break them up so that I have a list of overlapping groups of intervals. So, for example, with `Interval` as:

```
public class Interval {
    private final int start;
    private final int end;

    public Interval(int start,int end){
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    public int getStart(){return start;}
    public int getEnd(){return end;}

    public String toString(){ return "("+start+","+end+")"; }
}
```

And a `List<Interval>` like:

```
[(0,4),(1,7),(6,10),(13,17),(20,100),(22,31),(60,65)]
```

I want an output of `List<List<Interval>>`:

```
[[(0,4),(1,7),(6,10)],[(13,17)],[(20,100),(22,31),(60,65)]]
```

I can code this up, but I'm really enjoying the more functional approach of Java 8, and want to know if there is anything like an idiomatic way to do this using Java 8 streams.

I've had a look at the "group by" styles of provided [Collectors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html), but they don't seem to apply since I'm not really grouping by a classifier- you can't compute the groups based only on a property of each individual element, you have to consider the properties of each element in relation to the groups that have been computed so far.

Certainly there is non-crazy way to do this in functional languages (though I speak as someone who isn't really a functional programmer :-) ). How can I do it with streams in Java 8?

Comment: I guess, `this.start = end;` is not what you want. But it’s a good thing that you are using `final` variables so the error is immediately spot by the compiler.

Comment: By the way, what should be the output when the input is the following: `[(60, 65), (22, 31), (20, 100)]`? Should all three intervals be merged together? In other words, may the order of input intervals change the result?

Comment: @Tagir Valeev: the prerequisite of the question (in the first sentence) is that the elements are sorted by their start point. It’s easy to relax that requirement by prepending a sorting step to any solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot.  Streams are not suited to this sort of problem; streams have no notion of "previous elements" and are allowed to operate over elements in arbitrary order.  You can do it in Java, sure, and you can do it in functional languages, but that doesn't mean streams work like the functional language data structures you're used to.

Comment: Not all operations are allowed to process elements in arbitrary order. Allowing arbitrary order would make implementing, e.g. `Collectors.toList()`, very hard…

Comment: But toList does allow elements in arbitrary order, it just merges the accumulators together in an ordered fashion.

Comment: Well `toList()` is basically the same as `Collector.of(ArrayList::new, List::add, (left, right) -> { left.addAll(right); return left; })` and it obviously relies on the stream implementation invoking these functions in the right order if there is a defined encounter order. And the function expressed as `List::add` receives a list of all previous elements and a next element. It’s obvious that you can write your own collector relying on the same guarantees.

Answer (score 5):

Your were looking at the right place when studying the `groupingBy` collectors, but you are also right that they won’t provide the necessary logic for merging intervals. But they are conceptionally merging elements into the state created by previous elements. You have to implement a similar collector yourself.

Relying on your specification that the elements are already presorted by their start index, you can do it like:

```
Comparator<Interval> byStart = Comparator.comparingInt(Interval::getStart);
Comparator<Interval> byEnd   = Comparator.comparingInt(Interval::getEnd);
Collection<List<Interval>> merged = intervalList.stream().collect(
        () -> new TreeMap<Interval,List<Interval>>(byStart),
        (map,i) -> {
            Map.Entry<Interval,List<Interval>> e=map.floorEntry(i);
            if(e!=null && Collections.max(e.getValue(), byEnd).getEnd()>=i.getStart())
                e.getValue().add(i);
            else map.computeIfAbsent(i, x->new ArrayList<>()).add(i);
        },
        (m1,m2) -> m2.forEach((i,list) -> {
            Map.Entry<Interval,List<Interval>> e=m1.floorEntry(i);
            if(e!=null && Collections.max(e.getValue(), byEnd).getEnd()>=i.getStart())
                e.getValue().addAll(list);
            else m1.put(i, list);
        })
    ).values();
```

This creates a `Collection` rather than a `List`, but you can simply create a `List` out of it:

```
List<List<Interval>> list = new ArrayList<>(merged);
```

You should do that definitely if you intend to keep the result for a longer time rather than processing it immediately, as the `Collection` returned by the collector is a view into a `TreeMap` holding more resources than necessary.

I guess, in most cases you are better off with a loop based solution.

Comment: Nice solution! (1) I think the combiner is useless if the accumulator runs through every stream element serially (which must be the case if this solution is going to work). (2) Agreed: a loop is likely to be more transparent and efficient in this case.

Comment: @codeCogs: the combiner won’t be used for a sequential stream but it’s a good coding style to always provide a working combiner function to avoid surprises int the future. Formally, not doing so is even a violation of the API contract. The combiner of this solution works correctly, but goes to great lengths to achieve this, which can eat up any benefit of parallel processing, if there are any to begin with…

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem. Maybe what you can do is create multiple stream per group interval via filter then join all seperate stream together. If you want to create 3 groups then you create 3 seperate stream for each then join into one.